# How to get response with header code, body,... without Gson converter in Retrofit2 and Rx

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I've an issue. I want to get raw response (as byte stream) and manual convert body to model object (not using converter).

```
@GET("searchShop")
fun search(
        @Query("keyword") keyword: String,
        @Query("lat") location: Double? = null,
        @Query("lng") limit: Double? = null
): Observable<?????> // what should I put in there ?
```

I've search but I can't find out any solutions. Some bro tell me that pass `Response<T>` in `"?????"` but it throw exception:

> Unable to create converter for class T

What should I do? Many thanks!

Comment: That  `Observable` is that RxJava or LiveData?

Comment: it's part of RxJava, I'm not using LiveData in this project. Thanks!

Comment: retrofit api calling not working.

Comment: why used Observable here define Call<ResponseClass>.

Comment: @AndroidTeam I use retrofit with Rx thus I use Observable instead of Call.

Comment: Observable method put server response pojo class.

Comment: @AndroidTeam can you give me some page talk about that? Maybe I misunderstand

Comment: refer this link https://medium.freecodecamp.org/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff

Comment: sorry, but it seem be just a rx function. "As you’ll notice, I’m returning the Observable of WeatherData. That’s Rx right there!"

Comment: try `Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>`

Answer (score 0):

I've found out solution. Use `Observable<Response<ResponseBody>>` to handle this case. Thank every one!